# Paytm JS Checkout Module

Tags: payment-gateway, paytm

I wanted to integrate with th JS Checkout Module which Paytm has provided.I have done all the things like creating business account.I also have the access keys for both environments.
Js checkout getting started [guide](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/js-checkout/) says that we can customize the look and feel of the page but my issue is that In my dashboard under Developer Settings the JS Checkout Option is  **Disabled**.How can I get it enabled?
Can anyone please help me understand this. And guide me on how can I get started with this.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Is your test data ON? I cannot work on JS checkout with test data on/off mode.